# Flask - Adding Parameter to Route Breaks Images

Tags: python, html, flask, web-development-server

It seems I'm misunderstanding how the route in a Flask application is related to local files (images).

Basic example:

1. On the home page of my website (`@main_bp.route('/index')`, I have some content, including a navigation bar. The nav bar contains an image, call it `logo.svg`. The image in the nav bar always renders correctly on the home page ('/index').

The nav bar is rendered in `base.html`. The img src is `../static/images/logo.svg`

2. I have another page, call it `web_content/<content_number>`.

In `routes.py`, it looks like this: `@main_bp.route('/web_content/<content_number>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

Images, including `logo.svg` in the nav bar, render just fine when I navigate to this page. This page uses `{% extends 'base.html' %}`

3. I'm trying to add a layer in my website, call it `content_category`. So, modified routes.py like this: `@main_bp.route('/web_content/<content_category>/<content_number>`

This page renders, so I believe my code in routes.py is OK (content_category is defined in the function, etc.) **However, when I add the `content_category` parameter, the image in the nav bar breaks on the content page.** If I go back to the home page, the image in the nav bar renders just fine. So it doesn't seem to be a global breakage, only on the `/web_content` page when I add in another parameter.

This is confusing to me because I define the nav bar in only 1 place, `base.html`, and if the images render in one place I expect them to render everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a path like `../static/images/logo.svg` will make the browser load that image, relative to the path in the URL.  By adding parameters like `content_category` this is changing that URL path.

Instead use Flask's `url_for` function, in your template, to render the correct path dynamically:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.svg') }}" />
```